# (Assembly)How can I print on the console a hex number?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

Guys assume that I have the number 123456(or its binary) stored in the $t0 register.
Is there an easy way that I can print the number in its Hex form on the console?

Comment: Convert the number into the string representation you want, then print the string. Or switch to MARS and use system call 34.

Comment: How to convert the number into the string representation of the hex? thats the question

Comment: Each group of 4 bits of your number corresponds to one hex digit. So write a loop with some bitwise arithmetic. Write it in a higher-level language first if you don't know how to write it in assembly directly.

Comment: Can you help me with some assembly code? Im begginer on assembly